# Compile DBus on 64 bit Windows

Tags: dbus, mingw-w64

Ok, it's going to be a real nightmare for me to compile Qt5 on stupid windows platform. In first step I encountered a very strange error after hours of searching I found that it's because of .gitignore ! Why there should be a ignore pattern file in source release tarball? win7 refuses to create a file with no name so I used nano of MSYS to make it...

After successfully configuring Qt5, I installed requirements (OpenSSL, ICU etc.)

Then I found that there is no way to have a working DBus on 64 bit windows. I tried to compile various sources: [DBus4Win](http://repo.or.cz/w/dbus4win.git), [WinDBus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windbus), [KDE4Win](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kde-windows/) and original tarball from freedesktop.org. None of them even won't configure. The config script says that expat.h is nout found. I already compiled and installed expat in MSYS/mingw. Also tried [precompiled libraries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kde-windows/files/dbus/1.4.16/) fron KDE4Win project. They're nice but there is no debugging dll (compilation terminates with ld.exe error that -ldbus-1d not found). There is a tarball released for [debugging](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kde-windows/files/dbus/1.4.16/dbus-x86-mingw4-1.4.16-dbg.tar.bz2/download) version but it contains manifests.

Have you ever had success compiling Qt with DBus support on 64bit windows? How?

Answer (score 3):

Managed to compile version 1.6.8 with MSVC 2008 x64.
Didn't test it yet so it may work, it may not, it may crash.

Download from here -
http://rapidshare.com/files/2617500591/dbus-1.6.8-win64-TEST.zip

Comment: Thanks but I need minGW versions. These packages are available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/eboqt/files/mingw/x86_64/external-packages/